# Disable all sounds except currently playing

Tags: windows-7, audio, playback

I often work with music playing and as part of my work I browse various web pages. There ones with video playing by default or even with sound-enabled banners so I want to disable all sounds from playing except for application playing music (in my case it is foobar2000).

I am using Windows 7 as OS and foobar2000 as audio player.

If it possible I prefer to use native Windows solution which isn't involving any thrid-party applications.

Answer (score 6):

This is very easy in Windows Vista and above due to the new audio sub-system.

Simply click on the Audio icon and then mixer, and you can control sound on a per application basis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these settings persistent across reboots? (Guess I'll find out eventually anyway...)

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't show my browsers :-(

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica - if you right click the sound icon and do "open volume mixer", you can still do this!

Comment: I can open it; I can see that picture, but the apps listed do not include browsers

Answer (score 1):

Wil is correct, with one caveat: a web browser won't show up in Volume Mixer until it's actually playing sound (I've run into this problem myself in the past); so you'd have to load and play a video (or an embedded media player, flash game, etc) that uses sound in the browser, then open Volume Mixer to mute the browser.